# Balls A are circumferentially aligned with balls B

Tags: adverbs

[image]

I created the sentence below in order to describe the image above:

> Red balls are circumferentially aligned with blue balls.

But, after googled, I am afraid that the sentence may describe the image below:

[image]

Which image does my sentence describe? I think the first image can be simply described that **red balls are on the same circumference as blue balls**, but I want to use the term "circumferentially".

Comment: I (native speaker) would have no idea without the picture of what you meant by "circumferencially aligned". I would say "arranged in a circle", or "distributed round a circle".

Comment: Instead of this word you may use "Red balls are distributed on a circle and aligned with the blue balls". Also I would like to mention I can't see the images but guessing by the adverb used here!

Comment: "Red balls are alinged around a circle with blue balls" also should be the same.

Comment: American Heritage Dictionary define "align" as follow: To arrange in a line or so as to be parallel. The first image illustrates red balls are arranged in a line with blue balls circumferentially (in the circumferential direction of an object) while the second image illustrates red balls are arranged in parallel to blue balls circumferentially.  So, I think my sentence can describe both image.

Answer (score -1):

I think the second picture is the right one because according to oxfords dictionary, align means to arrange in a straight line. circumferentially means to put something in the circumference of the shape. So, it is picture number 2.

Comment: Software engineer here (with a degree in mathematics and computer science). I don't agree with this. Things can be _aligned_ in patterns and shapes other than a straight line, especially when a word like _circumferentially_, which explicitly invokes a nonlinear shape, is used to modify _aligned_. I would assume the meaning to be the first image. That said, I find "arranged/placed around the circumference of a circle" to be much clearer and less ambiguous.